# mobile version affecting desktop

Tags: javascript, css

I have this javascript that toggles a drop down nav menu in the mobile version. Then when I resize the browser to desktop size, the nav is messed up. How do I go back to the default styles after resizing the browser? thank you

```
icon.addEventListener("click", showMenu);
let executed = false;

function showMenu() {

if (executed == false) {
    nav.style.height = "0px";
    executed = true;

}
console.log(nav.style.height);
if (nav.style.height === "0px"){ //Want height only to be changed for mobile
nav.style.height = "460px";
} else {
    nav.style.height = "0px";
}
}
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', yourResetFunction);` but maybe you want it to trottle it

Comment: Consider using `@media` CSS rules instead of doing this in javascript.